# How can I convert a huge number from x base numbering system to y base numbering system?

Tags: arrays, c, numbers

I'm talking about numbers up to 9999 characters in length, so there's no converting that to decimal and putting it into an int. Numeric bases go up to 36 and anything above 9 is represented by an uppercase letter in alphabetic order. I have written a bit of code but I honestly only have a very vague idea on how to proceed. base1 is for the base of the numbering system the number was input in, base2 determines to what system it is to be converted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 1000

int exp(int expBase, int power) {
    unsigned int i = 1;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < power; j++)
        i *= expBase;
    return i;
}

void convert(char *num, int base1, int base2, int length) {
    char numC[LEN];
    int i;
}

int getNum(char *num) {
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != ' ') {
        num[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char num[LEN];
    int n, base1, base2, length;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        length = getNum(num);
        scanf("%d %d", &base1, &base2);
        convert(num, base1, base2, length);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There may be some mistakes in the code that I haven't noticed but this is only the first edition of it, not yet properly tested, so they're not relevant to the matter at hand. Thanks for any and all advice

Comment: "There may be some mistakes in the code that I haven't noticed ..." --> better for you to fix many known issues and then post code so we can focus on the key issue.  Lessor problems becomes a distraction as to what is really the part you are missing as "only have a very vague idea on how to proceed." lacks detail.  Consider posting your attempt at `convert()`.

Comment: Here is something to get started: `num[i]=c;` --> `num[i]=strtol((char[2]){c},0,36);` to convert character `c` to a value 0-35.

Comment: GMP has functions for converting bigints to and from strings with arbitrary bases.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use a library like the one suggested by Shawn, you'll have to code your own modulus and long division functions. Something like this... (the idivide function looks a little troublesome.) Code is not tested.

```
void touint8(char* num, uint8_t *numu8, int length) {
  for(int i=0 ; i<length; i++) {
    if (num[i] > '9') {
      numu8[length - i - 1] = num[i] - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
      numu8[length - i - 1] = num[i] - '0';
    }
  }
}

void fromuint8(uint8_t *numu8, char* num, int length) {
  // Inverse of touint8.
}

int idivide(uint8_t *numu8, int *length, int base1, int divisor) {
  // Perform integer long division of numu8 by divisor ...
  // Overwrite numu8 with result.
  return remainder;
}
        
char* convert(char* num, int base1, int base2, int length) {
  uint8_t *numu8 = malloc(length);
  uint8_t *resu8 = malloc(LEN);
  touint8(num, numu8, length);
  int resdigit = 0;
  while(length > 0) {
    resu8[resdigit] = idivide(numu8, &length, base1, base2);
    resdigit++;
  }
  char *res = malloc(resdigit+1);
  fromuint8(resu8, res, resdigit);
  free(numu8);
  free(resu8);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: `numu8[length - i - 1] = num[i] - 0x41;` Apart from bad use of _magic numbers_, this line **incorrectly** converts 'A' to `0` instead of `10`... Untested? Seems that way...

Comment: Code not tested, OK, yet `int getlsigdigit()`  does not even return a value.